# Admob Eu consent loadForm causing crash

Tags: android, admob

I am trying to show GDPR form for eu consent. its not working and causing crash when i test it through internal app testing. I am completely new to admob. I went to new privacy and messaging  options and i have this

[image]

public class HomeFragment extends BaseFragment implements MyAdapter.NoteListener, PurchasesUpdatedListener {

```
private ConsentInformation consentInformation;
private ConsentForm consentForm;



public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

            getConsentStatus();

        return root;
}  
 public void getConsentStatus(){

  
     ConsentRequestParameters params = new ConsentRequestParameters
             .Builder()
             .setTagForUnderAgeOfConsent(false)
             .build();

     consentInformation= UserMessagingPlatform.getConsentInformation(requireActivity());

     consentInformation.requestConsentInfoUpdate(requireActivity(), params,
             new ConsentInformation.OnConsentInfoUpdateSuccessListener() {
                 @Override
                 public void onConsentInfoUpdateSuccess() {

                     if(consentInformation.isConsentFormAvailable()){
                         try {
                             loadForm();
                         }catch (Exception e){debugToast(e.getMessage());}

                     }

                 }
             }, new ConsentInformation.OnConsentInfoUpdateFailureListener() {
                 @Override
                 public void onConsentInfoUpdateFailure(@NonNull FormError formError) {

                 }
             });


 }
 public void loadForm(){
    UserMessagingPlatform.loadConsentForm(
            requireActivity(),
            new UserMessagingPlatform.OnConsentFormLoadSuccessListener() {

                  @Override
                  public void onConsentFormLoadSuccess(@NonNull ConsentForm consentForm) {

                    HomeFragment.this.consentForm=consentForm;
            if(consentInformation.getConsentStatus()==ConsentInformation.ConsentStatus.REQUIRED){
                consentForm.show(requireActivity(), new ConsentForm.OnConsentFormDismissedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onConsentFormDismissed(FormError formError) {
                        try {
                            loadForm();
                        }catch (Exception e){debugToast(e.getMessage());}
                    }
                });
            }

        }
    }, new UserMessagingPlatform.OnConsentFormLoadFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onConsentFormLoadFailure(@NonNull FormError formError) {
            try {
                loadForm();
            }catch (Exception e){debugToast(e.getMessage());}
        }
    });
 }
```

crash happens when i uploadit on internal test track and install it . logs from firebase crashlatycs:

Fatal Exception: java.lang.VerifyError
Verifier rejected class com.navlab.recical.ui.home.HomeFragment: void com.navlab.recical.ui.home.HomeFragment.h1() failed to verify: void com.navlab.recical.ui.home.HomeFragment.h1(): [0x48] cannot access instance field c.c.b.b.e.d.z c.c.b.b.e.d.h.b from object of type Reference: java.lang.Object (declaration of 'com.navlab.recical.ui.home.HomeFragment' appears in /data/app/~~Hq2ou3cL8pLh7LMvC_brXA==/com.navlab.recical-OCMZc1E9XqZrpjokxu49Jg==/base.apk)

Comment: can you please update your question with error logs as well?

Comment: just did it. thanks

Comment: please check solutions provided on stackoverflow for error "Fatal Exception: java.lang.VerifyError Verifier rejected class". I don't think error is related to EU Form ( you can test this by removing EU Form code completely from your code and try running the application again )

Comment: it only happens with loadForm()